# STM32F4 Discovery ST-LINK no detection error

Tags: stm32, embedded

When these headers are on, I simply plug the STM32 to the computer by a micro USB expecting the embedded ST-LINK to upload the code to the system but I get "No ST-LINK detected!" error. Do you know what causes this problem?

In order to check the drivers, I have downloaded the STSW-LINK009 software and I ran "stlink_winusb_install.batch" and "dpinst_amd64" files and the device driver wizard said "the drivers were successfully installed on this computer". However, I am still getting the same error. Also, in the device manager under the Universal Serial Bus devices, I cannot see ST-LINK.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the driver installed correctly?

Comment: I couldn't find a driver actually, can you send me the link?

Comment: You can find everything on STM's website: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html.

Comment: It says the drivers are installed correctly but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: "It says the drivers are installed correctly": Who or what says it? Please provide more information: operating system, details for the installed drivers etc. Please also describe what software you are using for upload. And don't add it as a comment but edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Again: What software are you using for upload? And what does Device Manager say? It should like appear under *Disk drives*, *Ports (COM & LPT)* and *Universal Serial Bus devices* when you plug it in. Does it appear as an external drive?

Comment: It does not unfortunately.

Comment: If you cannot see the ST-Link in the device manager (and cannot hear the sound when you plug it in), then either your USB cable is broken, your development board is broken or you have connected it to the wrong USB port on the board. The correct one would be the USB mini port near the jumpers.

Comment: My development board's leds are working actually, and yes I have connected it to the USB mini port near CN3 on the figure.

Comment: So the most likely culprit is the USB cable. It might be a cable with power wires only and poor contact with the data lines.

Comment: Interestingly, when I changed the USB cable it worked with another cable. Thank you.